# Forward credentials from app to credential provider

Tags: c++, windows, credentials, credential-providers

I've started to investigate how credential providers work, but due to poor documentation I got stuck in couple of places.

I have console application(sort of like ssh server) when I connect remotly to this application and authenticate(none is logged on), I want it to be able to forward those credentials to credential provider and I want CP to login user(create session).

I've also noticed that In documentation it says that `SetSerialization` method always gets called after `SetusageScenario`. But I've added logs and `SetSerialization` never gets called after `SetusageScenario`.

As I know `SetSerialization` is called when credential is provided by application. I can't understand what does it mean to provide credential through application? It seems like this is what I need, to forward credentials from application to credential provider, but How can I do that? Are there some functions that I could call from credential provider dll to provoke login?

Is there any way I can achieve this? I've read that when remote login is done, `UpdateRemoteCredential` is called, But As I understand(correct me if I'm wrong) in remote login it means `RDP` but my application is simple, it just listens to some port and gets username and password and then uses `Logonuser` function.

A program named `MxLogon2` implements this scheme. A remote server with `MxLogon2` installed can authenticate a USB key(But I want username/password) connected to the client side in a remote desktop session.

Any suggestion that would direct me to right way would be greatly appriciated.

**P.S**

I'm using `pGina` as my credential provider.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't mind too much of SetSerialization in your case. This is used for pre-initializing tile.

One example would be, with RDP connection, you can store certificates of credentials on your system. This function is used to pre-inquire tiles with those credentials (not the only solution though).

Make it return E_NOTIMPL in your case.

The main purpose of the provider is to initialize Credentials and tiles :

1. **Credentials initialization**

is done through SetUsageScenario function (automatically called after Provider construction).
In there, you can customize the behavior depending on scenario you are in. Most basic one being CPUS_LOGON.
It shall look like this (this is only a preview)

```
HRESULT Provider::SetUsageScenario(
__in CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus,
__in DWORD dwFlags
)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    switch(cpus)
    {
        case CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION:
        case CPUS_LOGON:
        hr = this->_InitCredential();
        break;

        default:
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
        break;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

2. **Tiles initialization**

begins in GetCredentialCount function. It allows you to define how many tiles you gonna show (pdwCount out parameter), as well as the one to be used as the default tile (pdwDefault).
Auto-Logon is also handle in here (through pbAutoLogonWithDefault).

Tiles Enumeration is then beginning in GetCredentialAt function.

Passing credentials for authentication is done in the credential you're using through the GetSerialization function.

Examples of implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/CredentialProvider/cpp/CSampleCredential.cpp).
I hardly insist on example as it easily divert depending on what you are trying to achieve. This is very flexible and you'd better understand the purpose of any function / parameter to fit your goals.

EDIT - cf comments :

```
#define IDCredential        0x1

Credential::Credential(Provider* parent)
{
    //Do ssh connection or whatever

    if(success)
    {
        parent->login = retrievedLogin;
        parent->pwd = retrievedPwd;
        parent->CredentialUsed = IDCredential;
        parent->autoLogin = true;
        parent->ProviderEvents->CredentialsChanged(AdviseContext);
    }
}

HRESULT Provider::GetCredentialCount(
    __out DWORD* pdwCount,
    __out_range(<,*pdwCount) DWORD* pdwDefault,
    __out BOOL* pbAutoLogonWithDefault
    )
{
    if(this->autoLogin && this->CredentialUsed)
    {
        *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = true; // --> Instant call to GetSerialization
        *pdwDefault = this->CredentialUsed; //index of the tile
    }
    else
    {
        *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = false;
        *pdwDefault = IDCredential;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the question was how to forward credentials from application to credential provider when none is logged on, create session(remotly) without any physical interaction. I didn't understand how your answer fits in.

Comment: I agree most of my answer is focused on answering the side-question you asked. But as i said in the lower part of the answer, the credential is supposed to load your application. Then it callback to GetSerialization for providing login/password.
Did i misunderstand something ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. As I know `GetSerialization` is called after I click submit button on UI and submit this credential to the underlying authentication engine right? You are saying that `Credential is supposed to load your application` what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Click Submit button or you can also use the autoLogin feature by calling CredentialsChanged event. It will callback to GetCredentialCount which will call to GetSerialization if AutoLogon is enabled. This is for the no-physical interaction.
What i mean is, i'm personnaly loading a c++ dll and i'm starting a thread for 'wait login/password from dll'. But in your case, it would be ssh server connection or whatever you usually do to retrieve data.

Comment: So As I understand I can lunch some thread from credential provider(for example wait for user/pass by pipe), receive creds and then call `CredentialsChanged` which will call `GetSerialization` and eventually log in?

Comment: In the condition that autoLogon is activated and that you provide a valid default Credential. I'll update my answer to make an "example" of how i would do.

Comment: Thanks for example. But I think we misunderstood each other. In your example credential provider would connect to something and retrieve credentials from there. What I want is that when LogonUI is hit(machine A), then when someone tries to connect to machine A(using my app ssh alike), I want this app to forward those credentials to provider and create session.

Comment: Oh. No clue sorry. I can't remember of any feature about ssh connection listening...

Comment: Maybe I could have like a thread in credential provider listening to a pipe, my app would write username and password there, Can I then fill username/password field on UI and hit submit programatically from credential provider?

Comment: That would work as long as you successfully listen to your pipe. Credential only asks for login/password. It doesn't care of what you're doing in between.

Comment: Do you know function which would do that? Like which function would emit clicking the submit button?

Comment: Refer to the example i added to my answer.
Submit Click call Connect which call GetSerialization.
CredentialsChanged call GetCredentialCount which call GetSerialization if autoLogon is enabled.

Comment: and How can I set some strings in username/password field?